# php stream_select is returning streams that have nothing to read

Tags: php, websocket

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
stream_select($streamsReadyToRead , $lcNull, $lcNull, 0, 31250);
```

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php), This is supposed to "see if characters become available for reading", and `$streamsReadyToRead` should be populated with *just* the streams that are ready to be read.
however, I'm reading the sockets like this:

```
  foreach ($streamsReadyToRead as $streamToRead)
  {
    $text = fgets($streamToRead);
    if (empty($text))
    {
        echo "This should never happen, but does!";
    }
  }
```

If I send something small through the stream, it works fine. When I go over 1000 chars or so, it sometimes reads *nothing*!

Is there something I'm not understanding? Why is `stream_select` telling me the socket has characters available for reading when actually there's nothing ready for reading yet?

Comment: For anyone interested, I never found the solution to this. It seems like this PHP function is slightly broken. You just have to write your script so that it anticipates that the socket may not actually have any data to read, even though PHP says it does.